# What Komodo color scheme do you use?

Tags: color-scheme, komodo, komodoedit

I'm looking for a good color scheme for Komodo IDE.

Comment: Normally, after installing it, the first thing I change is simply the color of selected text, as it light gray and this is not suggestive of selected contents, but of disabled contents.

Answer (score 2):

I made my own color scheme, but I based in upon a theme I have for gedit called Darkmate, seen here: http://grigio.org/tag/darkmate

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Twilight for the past 2 months, PHP development. I've got it from here:
http://www.gravitywell.co.uk/blog/post/komodo-color-scheme-twilight